# How to make a background responsive not only vertically or horizontally but both?

Tags: html, css, background, resize, responsive

I want to create a login page which has a picture background.
I like this login portal [office login page](https://login.microsoftonline.com/) so it's a reference to me. I noticed that on office login page, picture is not affected from vertically or horizontally resize but if i change from the corner it's resizing.

I've tried to change width and height attributes with several types (like; auto, % or vh) but i could'nt find the correct settings for that.

What is the magic behind this? Is there any javascript activities that i missed?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use background-size and background-position at the same time to get that:

```
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: background-position does not have fixed value but i guess you tried to say background-attachment. I tried and it is working. Thanks

Comment: Oh yes, my bad sorry